# override font-size in jssor slider when scaled down

Tags: jssor

Is it possible to reset font-size when slider is in 'responsive' mode?
I have a slider that woks very well until the screen size goes down below about 740px wide. Then type becomes almost impossible to read.

So I tried to override font-sizes with media queries. No luck. Turns out transform: scale(0.32298) - or some decimal like that - gets applied to one of the parent containers. Tried overriding that too, but didn't get far with that either.

Is there a 'canonical' way to preserve/override scaling effects? ... callbacks, etc.?

EDIT:

transform appears as an inline style:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 654px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; transform: scale(0.34454345703125);">

it appears in the first child of <div id="slider1_container"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have a specific class that gets applied when you reach 140px? You say 'responsive' mode, how do you know this is applied?

Comment: ... added a bit of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up using cycle2 plugin. Turned out to be pretty flexible and was able to restyle contents with media queries without any issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think you have some content elements as below in any slide in your slider.

```
<div style="...font-size: 50px; ...">You text</div>
```

Please move inline styles to css block, and then you get following format,

```
<div class="classname">You text</div>
```

In this manner, you have chance to apply different font-size on various screen.

```
<style>
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
        .classname {
            font-size: ...px;
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .classname {
            font-size: ...px;
        }
    } 
</style>
```

Comment: that's all and good, i can control the font sizes, i can't control the height of their wrappers very well - i'm guessing due to the transform rules on the grand-parent element(s). I have no inline styling on parts i need to control. it's the lack of control over scaling that's the problem.